# Copy records of one table to another before converting date column from varchar to datetime format in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, data-warehouse

i need to copy record of one table to another but before doing it, i need to convert my date stamp column (nvarchar) in datetime format because the date there is in varchar format and because of which i m not able to query the table. I know how to convert the varchar in datetime format, but it is for a single record. Can any one refer me a simple and fast way to do this that convert the the whole column in date time format and then copy record to another table.the e.g. format of the varchar datestamp is wenesday, january 16, 2013.

```
declare @dateString varchar(50)
set @dateString = 'wednesday, january 16, 2013'

declare @index int
set @index = charindex( ',', @dateString )
set @dateString = substring( @dateString, @index + 1, len(@dateString) - @index)

select cast(@dateString as datetime)
```

the code above converts a varchar of my format in datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using MS SQL Server, not MYSQL.

All you should need to do is take your function logic there, replace the @index in your substring function with `charindex(',' columnname)` and put it as part of your `SELECT` statement in your INSERT..SELECT

```
INSERT ....
SELECT cast(
    substring( COLUMN
              , charindex( ',', COLUMN ) + 1
              , len(COLUMN) - charindex( ',', COLUMN )
             ) as datetime
           ) from XXX
```

[A full example is available on this SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/043ae/3)

Comment: can u plz be more clearer as i didn't get some points u said?

Comment: @ N WEST
i assumed the way u said as
"
declare dateString varchar(50)

INSERT set dateString = substring( dateString, charindex(',' datestamp) + 1, len(dateString) - charindex(',' datestamp))
SELECT cast(
    substring( datestamp
              , charindex( ',', datestamp ) + 1
              , len(datestamp) - charindex( ',', datestamp)
             ) as datetime
           ) from inoutlogs
"
i get error @ the substring line, can u plz tell why?
note: i removed the @ signs because stackoverflow think it is for a user and gives error

Comment: thanks. plz provide it to me as my database section is weak,..hope u understand

Comment: @ N WEST
u saved my time..i achieved my goal after some changes...thanks...hats of for u

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had resolved it this way.

1. Make a copy of the entire table with prefix - example table1 -> backup_table1
2. Delete all raws from the original table e.g. make it empty
3. Change the varcher fields in the original table to date or datetime. I have changed mine from VARCHAR to DATE.
4. Copy all the information from the backup table to the original one but with dates directly converted with the sql query. I was converting field1 and field2 
   from dd-mm-YY to YY-mm-dd

I used this:

```
INSERT INTO original_table
(field1, field2, field3, field4 ...)
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(field1, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'), 
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(field`, '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d'), 
field3, filed4 ...
FROM backup_table
```

This way as I copy the information and convert directly the varchar dates to DATE format sql standars format.
Hope this will help to someone.